# Youtrack - change base url problems

Tags: configuration, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

I have installed youtrack on centos 7. 
It is hosted at 111.111.111.111 .
It is available from youtrack.mydomain.com.
When i installed youtrack i set it's base url on 111.111.111.111, but then changed to youtrack.mydomain.com .

Now everything works like youtrack.mydomain.com/hub , youtrack.mydomain.com/issues etc, but the problem is that when i go to projects and click on an issue from widget(issue list), it **redirects** me to **111.111.111.111/issues/issue-number**, while it would need to redirect to **youtrack.mydomain.com/issues/issue-number**

I have tried to configure with :
./youtrack.sh configure --base-url=youtrack.mydomain.com
./youtrack.sh configure --hub-url=youtrack.mydomain.com
Configured system settings in youtrack and hub . Nothing works.
One of my choices is to redirect 111.111.111.111 to youtrack.mydomain.com with iptables, but that is a workaround and i should try solving it only within youtrack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this one need to update the widget to the recent version:

1. In admin menu select 'Custom Widgets' item
2. Select 'YouTrack Issues List' widget and hit [Update]

YouTrack server should be able to establish a connection to https://plugins.jetbrains.com for this to work.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-49641